# Proof that P is an Orthogonal Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, orthogonality

I'm studying linear algebra using Axler's text and am stuck on 6.17.

The problem is: Prove that if $P \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is such that $P^2 = P$ and every vector in $\operatorname{null} P$ is orthogonal to every vector in
$\operatorname{range} P$, then $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

My proof so far: Suppose $P \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is such that $P^2 = P$ and every vector in $\operatorname{null} P$ is orthogonal to every vector in
$\operatorname{range} P$. Let $v \in P$. We have a decomposition $V =  \operatorname{range} T \oplus \operatorname{null} T 
= \operatorname{range} T \oplus (\operatorname{range} T)^\perp$. Then each vector $v \in V$ can be uniquely represented in the form 
$v = u + w$ where $u \in \operatorname{null} P$ and $w \in \operatorname{range} P$.

We have $Pv=P(u + w)=Pu+Pw=Pw=P^2w$.

I would appreciate some hints on how to finish my proof. I have the idea that from here, we can derive that $P(u+w)=w$ which would complete the proof (please correct me if I'm wrong).

To begin with, a hint on how $P^2 = P$ is useful would be very helpful.

Comment: I just found these hints courtesy of U. Michigan: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mityab/teaching/m296w12/hints7.pdf and will try to use them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

You know that $w$ is in the range of $P$, and so $w = Px$ for some $x \in V$.

Try using this and the fact that $P^2 = P$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used your hint to help complete my proof. Could you please take a look and help me know if it makes sense:

We know that $w \in \operatorname{range} P$ and so $w= Px$ for some $x \in V$. We can use that $P$ is idempotent to show $P^2x=P(Px)=Pw
=w$. 

Using the above result, we can show $P(v)=P(u+w)=P(u)+P(w)=w$. Therefore, $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: It's almost there, but not quite. The reasoning in the middle should be something more like $P^2x = Px$, by idempotence. Thus, as $Pw = P(Px)$, $Pw = Px = w$.